# React - Pass child dropdown menu state to parent

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to set up a page that uses React. The page has a dropdown menu component, which should trigger an update of state in the parent. I have tried following several examples but cannot get anything to work. Here is a simplified example for both methods I've tried:

1. Pass a callback as a prop to the child which updates the parent state:

   ```
   let Example = React.createClass({

   getInitialState() {
       test: "fail"
   },
   _updateOnChange(value) {
       this.setState({test: value})
   },
   render() {
       return (<div><DropDown onValueChange=this._updateOnChange} />
       <p>{this.state.test}</p></div>);
   }    
   });

   let DropDown = React.createClass({
   getInitialState() {
       return { value: "fail" };
   },
   _onChangeHandler(e) {
       this.setState({value: e.target.value});
       this.props.onValueChange(this.state.value);
   },

   render() {
       return (
           <select onChange={this._onChangeHandler} value={this.state.value}>
               <option value="1">1</option>
               <option value="2">2</option>
           </select>
       );
   }
   ```

   });

This always displays "fail" rather than "1" or "2".

2. Have the parent grab the value of the dropdown menu using onChange instead of a callback.

   ```
   let Example = React.createClass({
   getInitialState() {
       test: "fail"
   },
   _updateOnChange(e) {
       this.setState({test: e.target.value})
   },
   render() {
      return (<DropDown onChange=this._updateOnChange} />);
   }
   ```

   });

   ```
   let DropDown = React.createClass({
   getInitialState() {
       return { value: "fail" };
   },
   _onChangeHandler(e) {
       this.setState({value: e.target.value});
   },

   render() {
       return (
           <select onChange={this._onChangeHandler} value={this.state.value}>
               <option value="1">1</option>
               <option value="2">2</option>
           </select>
       );
   }
   ```

   });

I can see the state change within the DropDown component if I try to render the state, but the parent does not change. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is it possible for you to create a quick jsFiddle or something please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first approach should work just fine with couple of changes

The method getInitialState should return an object like this

```
getInitialState() {
  return { test: "fail" }
}
```

The _onChangeHandler in the DropDown component has a problem. You have two ways to solve this

#### Option 1

The second line `this.props.onValueChange(this.state.value);` will not execute after the state has been set and hence it will display old values. setstate definition looks like this

> setState(function|object nextState[, function callback])

use the callback function to make sure that the state has been set and then this.prop executes

```
_onChangeHandler(e) {
  var self = this;
  this.setState({value: e.target.value}, function(){
    self.props.onValueChange(self.state.value); // <---- Makes sure that the state has been set at this stage
  });
},
```

#### Option 2

instead of passing `this.state.value` just send `e.target.value` like this

```
_onChangeHandler(e) {
  this.setState({value: e.target.value});
  this.props.onValueChange(e.target.value); // <--- pass the value directly
},
```

Here is a demo **https://jsfiddle.net/dhirajbodicherla/aqqcg1sa/4/**